# Getting status from IntuitBatchResponse

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I am using an IntuitBatchRequest to insert several invoices into Quickbooks Online.  I am trying to understand the response properties to know which invoices were successful and what the specific problem was for those that were not successful.  I am trying two different methods for reviewing the results.  Once procedure loops through them for logging.  The simplified version of the code looks like the following:

```
Dim invcResponse as BatchItemResponse
For each invcResponse in lclBatchResponse.BatchItemResp
    batchID=invcResponse.bId 
    faultType=invcResponse.Fault.type
Next invcResponse
```

The other code binds the response to a grid for my review.  A snippet of the grid code looks like:

```
<asp:GridView id="gv_BatchStatus" runat="server">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
    Item<asp:Label id="lbl_item" runat="server" text='<%# Bind("Item.Id.value") %>'></asp:Label>
    Fault<asp:Label id="lbl_flt" runat="server" text='<%# Bind("Fault.type") %>'></asp:Label>
```

The above properties work.  But, when I try to bind to Fault.Error.Code, it tells me that Intuit.Ipp.Data.Error[] does not contain a property with the name 'code'.  However, the class list for Error says it has properties, which include code, detail, element, and message.  These properties also show as string properties of Error in the Object Browser within Visual Studio.  So, here are my questions...
1. What property and value is the definitive determination of success?
2. How do I get more information on the error?  The only error property that I can figure out (Fault.type) just tells me that I am getting an ID exception.

Comment: Correction: The gridview binding of Item.id.value is not returning anything - maybe because the insert failed.  I am not sure.  However, the bId (batch ID) is displayed by autogenerate of the columns.

Comment: After a closer look, I believe the issue may be that the Error property of Fault is an array of errors.  I will try some code to see if I can get the values.

Comment: You can get the error details by iterating through the error array.  Each error object in the list has the properties: code, detail, element, and message.  Message is the most user friendly description.  It would still be very helpful to know the certain way to know if there was success.  Do you check for Fault object is nothing? ...or if the item object is not nothing?

Answer (score 2):

I just completed a successful batch request.  Within the iterative code mentioned above to loop through the response items, I am using the following code to determine if each invoice was successful.

```
`If invcResponse.Fault is Nothing then 
    sStatus="OK"
else 
    For each error in invcResponse.Fault.Error 
        sStatus=sStatus & oError.Message &", " 
    Next oError 
End If`
```

This seems to be consistent with the documentation and the response I am getting.